# Grouping a percentage calculation in postgres/redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, percentage

I keep running in to the same problem over and over again, hoping someone can help...

I have a large table with a category column that has 28 entries for donkey breed, then I'm counting two specific values grouped by each of those categories in subqueries like this:

```
WITH totaldonkeys AS (
    SELECT donkeybreed,
           COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM donkeytable1
    GROUP BY donkeybreed
)
,
sickdonkeys AS (
    SELECT donkeybreed,
           COUNT(*) AS totalsick
    FROM donkeytable1
    JOIN donkeyhealth on donkeytable1.donkeyid = donkeyhealth.donkeyid
    WHERE donkeyhealth.sick IS TRUE
    GROUP BY donkeybreed
)
,
```

It's my goal to end up with a table that has primarily the percentage of sick donkeys for each breed but I always end up struggling like hell with the problem of not being able to group by without using an aggregate function which I cannot do here:

```
SELECT (CAST(sickdonkeys.totalsick AS float) / totaldonkeys.total) * 100 AS percentsick,
                totaldonkeys.donkeybreed
    FROM totaldonkeys, sickdonkeys
    GROUP BY totaldonkeys.donkeybreed
```

When I run this I end up with 28 results for each breed of donkey, one correct I believe but obviously hundreds of useless datapoints.

I know I'm probably being really dumb here but I keep hitting in to this same problem again and again with new donkeydata, I should obviously be structuring the whole thing a new way because you just can't do this final query without an aggregate function, I think I must be missing something significant.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I would avoid the word "obvious" at all costs on this site.

Comment: Just to update in case anyone else sees this, it's the mad way I'm calling the two tables in the last query that is the problem. I'd used it as a technique recently and it was not appropriate here, a join on donkeybreed fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily count the proportion that are sick in the `donkeyhealth` table

```
SELECT d.donkeybreed,
       AVG( (dh.sick)::int ) AS proportion_sick
FROM donkeytable1 d JOIN
     donkeyhealth  dh
     ON d.donkeyid = dh.donkeyid
GROUP BY d.donkeybreed
```

Comment: Hey hey, thanks for replying :) 

I fudged the context a lot, it wasn't originally about donkeys ;)

I really want to just end up with the percentage of the subset of the whole as defined by data in two other tables. 

I have tried your suggestion here, the problem I'm running in to is it's an invalid operation due to the WHERE condition on donkey health being the validation of a string rather than an integer value. 

I guess maybe I'm being unhelpful, sorry, I feel like there must be a way to calculate percentages like this that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: And I actually have two different where conditions dependant on two different tables to assign that a donkey is sick...

Comment: @MrGrumpy . . . Actually, the `where` clause should not be there at all.  As for `AVG( (dh.sick)::int )` . . . you need a boolean expression there, something like `AVG( (dh.status = 'sick')::int )`.